# Insert в конкретный столбец в зависимости от месяца в строке

Tags: sql, база-данных, plsql

Прошу помочь с написанием процедуры - честно говоря, не знаю как построить алгоритм.
Есть таблица (ТАБЛ1 условно) с 13 столбцами: 1 - ID - ключ по другой таблице (ТАБЛ2 условно), и столбцы с наименованиями месяцев (условно DEC - JAN)
При выполнении процедура должна делать следующее:
Для каждой записи в ТАБЛ1 должна заглянуть по ID в ТАБЛ2 - там в соответствующей записи взять значение из столбца с датой (условно - ДАТА), вытащить из нее число, и вставить в ТАБЛ1 в столбец, соответствующий месяцу - т.е. если дата 01.01.2017, то в ТАБЛ1 в столбец JAN должно вставиться значение 01.
Код писать не нужно - мне необходимо узнать верный алгоритм такой процедуры.

Comment: в принципе решается в один запрос с `pivot`. НО этого делать не следует потому, что ваша таблица с колонками-месяцами нарушает первую нормальную форму и практически не имеет права на существование в реляционной БД.

Comment: Добрый день. Похоже, что тут можно использовать обычный `INSERT ... SELECT`. Реализация `SELECT` может быть подзапросами, т.е. `SELECT` на каждый столбец. А вообще, по ощущениям, вы строите что-то излишне громоздкое. Возможно, вам стоит подумать над структурой хранения данных?

Comment: В явной форме. *мне необходимо узнать верный алгоритм такой процедуры* - верный алгоритм начинается с (да практически состоит из) внесения изменений в структуру БД с целью нормализации данных. Конечная структура таблицы должна быть `tab2_id - month - value`, первичный ключ `(tab2_id, month)` либо синтетический.

Comment: Как минимум ТАБЛ1, необходимо структурно расположить вертикально со столбцами: idRow, ID - ключ по другой таблице, MONTH_NAME, MONTH_VAL. При таком подходе последующие, описанные Вами действия, реализовать будет гораздо проще.

Comment: Переделал таблицу ТАБЛ1 под 3 столбца (ID, MONTH_NAME, MONTH_VAL). В итоге это должен был получиться график (по x - ID, по y - месяцы, на пересечениях - даты), но как теперь привести к такому виду я , честно говоря, не знаю.

Правка - наврал) решил нужным образом применив decode